# Error converting an array into an integer

Tags: pic, communication

I'm trying to send a number from a PC to a PIC18f4550 as an array using USART and then converting it to an integer using a routine inside the PIC.

The problem arrives that in some cases the integer is not the same number as the array (it's usually 1 unit less) like I show in the image.

[image]

```
#include <18F4550.h>
#include <math.h>
#FUSES NOWDT, XT, NOPUT, NOPROTECT, NOBROWNOUT, NOLVP, NOCPD, NOWRT, NODEBUG
#use delay (clock = 20000000)
#use rs232(uart1, baud=9600)
int count[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
int pulses=0;
int i=0;
int j=0;

void main()
{
 while(true)
   {
      delay_ms(10);
      pulses=0;
      for(i=0; i<5; i++)   //Converts the array into an integer
      {
         pulses=pulses+count[4-i]*pow(10,i);
      }
      printf("P: %u    ",pulses);   //Prints the integer and the used array
      for(i=0; i<5; i++)
      {
         printf("%u ",count[i]);
      }
      printf("\r");
      if(count[4]<9)   //Increases the array in 1
         count[4]++;
      else
      {
         count[4]=0;
         if(count[3]<9)
            count[3]++;
         else
         {
            count[3]=0;
            if(count[2]<9)
               count[2]++;
            else
            {
               count[2]=0;
               if(count[1]<9)
                  count[1]++;
               else
               {
                  count[1]=0;
                  count[0]++;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: CCS C Compiler PCH v4.013 @BruceAbbott

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem but you should be using %d in the printf()s not %ld, you are printing 16 bit signed numbers not 32 bit unsigned numbers.

Comment: As for the actual problem, the screen shots were generated by the exact code posted? That shouldn't be possible. If the data in the count array was coming from the PC then it could be some timing related problem but as posted the code isn't reading anything from the PC.

Comment: @Andrew I use %ld because I need to print 16 bit unsigned integer. The screenshots were generated using the exact same code posted, it's reading data from Proteus virtual terminal and it gives me those results. Something strange is that all numbers finishing in 99 (99, 199, 299, etc) are repeated once

Comment: @Andrew correction, this program is not reading values from the virtual terminal, I used this program to test where the problem is because I had the same problems sending the data across the virtual terminal, eliminating it I could see the problem doesn't rely on the USART communication

Comment: @MarceloEspinozaVargas You use %lu - that means treat the data as a long (meaning 32 bit) unsigned integer. You then pass it an int16 data type. Even %ld as in your comment is incorrect, that is a 32 bit signed integer not 16 bit. Since all your values are under 2^15 they will still display correctly but that doesn't make the code correct. For an int16 data type you should use %d.

Comment: So is the output you show the output from the code you posted? If not please edit the question so that it is. Don't post the output from one program and then the code from a different one.

Comment: It's the actual code, I thought I was using %ld but you're correct, I'm actually using %lu, I'll try to use %d and see if it's affecting the code

Comment: @Andrew I changed the code to %u, I tried with %d but the integer only reached 127 and then it went to -127, the pictures are from the code listed on the post and the error is the same

Comment: OK. I have a guess as to what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK it looks like your compiler doesn't follow the c standard.

In c an int is defined as being at least 16 bits. The compiler you are using defines an int as 8 bits. That is why when using an int you wrap around at 255 (or 127 for signed numbers).

Since you only use unsigned values make points an unsigned int16. (and ignore my earlier comments, use %lu in the printf() calls since your compiler thinks that 16 bits is a long)

The pow() function should return a double however it looks like your compiler only supports floats, either way I'm guessing the errors you are seeing are rounding related when converting back from a float/double to an integer.
You calculation was int = int + int*float, the float takes precedence over the int and so you end up with int = float. The compiler then automatically casts the float back to an int. When doing this in c the system will always round down. So if the result was 9.99999999 instead of 10 due to floating point rounding errors you end up getting 9 not 10.

You could solve this by adding 0.5 to each calculation, it will then round to the nearest integer rather than rounding down. However best option is probably to avoid all the floating point stuff completely. Doing everything with integers will be both faster and more reliable.

Try:

```
pulses=0;
//Converts the array into an integer, [0] is most significant
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
  pulses = pulses*10 + count[i];
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you so much for the support

Comment: "The compiler you are using defines an int as 8 bits". I never liked the CCS compiler, but now I also have a good reason :-)

Comment: @m.Alin it gets worse: "All types, except float char, by default are unsigned (Except int64 may only be signed)" So not only are all their sizes wrong, their default sign is too. An int should be a 16 bit or more signed value, it is an 8 bit unsigned value. A long long int should be a signed 64 bit number, it's an unsigned 32 bit number.

Comment: Damn.. that's so stupid..